# How to display a local image in blazor in img src?

Tags: html, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am using `blazor` `webassembly` and I want to display a local image in `img` `src`.

there will be an `input type ='file'` and when user tap a image in his device.

can I get the path and display it in src?

```
<img src="my image" />

<img src="c:\\users\\my user\\0001.jpg" />
```

Comment: I can't imagine a greater security risk than that, and it's not a Blazor issue, it's an HTML / browser security issue.  I suspect you'll have to actually upload the file, save it, and then use a relative link for your `img src`, even though the file is on the same device as the browser.

Comment: You might still see posts, even on SO, saying you can do that, but check the date.  It hasn't been possible for +10 years.  Also see: [File and Directory Entries API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API)

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 the user pick the image and then display in local img where is the risk?

Comment: @Yogi thank you and I got it NO!!!!!! I want to create a website for hobby so I only want to create a static files website. but now I have to get a server now.

Comment: @liang.good The browser doesn't know the relationship between the site designer, the client, the file system and the browser software.  Any time you have something changeable-- like a string description of a real file path-- that is dangerous.